# Use undeclared type error: How to compare object with class type?

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

How to compare `object` with `AnyClass` generic type:

I want to compare an object with the type of class and the class name should be passed as an argument.

```
func checkGeneric(className: AnyClass) {
    let object = UIViewController()
    if (object is className) { // Use of undeclared type `className`
        print(className)
    }
}

checkGeneric(className: UIViewController.self)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `type(of:)` to get the type of the `object` and compare it with `AnyClass`. Try this..

```
func checkGeneric(className: AnyClass) {
    let object = UIViewController()
    if (type(of: object) == className) { // Use of undeclared type class name
        print(className)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with isKinOf

```
func checkGeneric(className: AnyClass)
    {
        print(className)
        let object = UIViewController()
        if object.isKind(of: className) {
            print("yes")
        } else {
            print("no")
        }

    }

    checkGeneric(className: UIViewController.self)
    checkGeneric(className: NSMutableArray.self)
```

**OUPUT**

```
UIViewController
yes
NSMutableArray
no
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func checkGeneric(className: AnyClass) {
    let object = ViewController()
    if (object.isKind(of: className)) {
        print("Class Name is : \(className)")
    }
}

checkGeneric(className: ViewController.self)
```

You can compare object with class using isKind(),

```
let viewController = UIViewController()

viewController.isKind(of: ViewController.self)
```